# Array duplicate object while pushing object

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I am trying to push object on the array its duplicate all the object to the last pushed object.

```
 var seriesArr = [];
 var seriesDemo = {};

 var seriesFinal = finalArr[0]

 for (var o in finalArr[0]) {
    seriesDemo.valueField = o;
    seriesArr.push(seriesDemo);
 }
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{"valueField":"amount[3]"},{"valueField":"amount[3]"},{"valueField":"amount[3]"},{"valueField":"amount[3]"}]

It should be like: [{"valueField":"amount[0]"},{"valueField":"amount[1]"},{"valueField":"amount[2]"},{"valueField":"amount[3]"}]
```

Comment: What is value of finalArr ?

Comment: forget about `seriesDemo` object and do like `seriesArr.push({valueField:o});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this?

```
for (var o in finalArr[0]) {
   var seriesDemo = {}; // (Re-)Initialize here
   seriesDemo.valueField = o;
   seriesArr.push(seriesDemo);
}
```

The problem is that you are updating the global `seriesDemo` hash everytime and it is pushed into `seriesArr` by reference. So all entries in `seriesArr` are holding reference to the last entry.